# how to use a macro in one workbook to trigger another workbook's macro

Tags: excel, vba

I already created a workbook with Macro to have 40 people to use it. So the end user just need to click the button, and the worksheet will give the end user the next available client information. However, as this is a shared file, if one person click the button while another person is opening it, that person could not open it. So I am thinking to create another workbook as end user's interface. The original workbook will be the back end. 
We call the original work as A, the new one as B. I want to use Marco in B to trigger the Macro in A. When the end user click a button in B, it is the same as clicking the button in A. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you are trying to call macro test in Module1 of worksheet A,

```
Application.Run "'C:\Users\Yui\Desktop\A.xlsm'!Module1.test"
```